# ROS Answers SE migration: urdf to xacro

Tags: urdf, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm building my first robot and I'm not understanding XACRO.

I did the robot in urdf and now I'm changing the file to xacro. But I get a lot or errors.

```
Expat parsing error.  Check that:
 - Your XML is correctly formed
 - You have the xacro xmlns declaration: xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro"

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/share/xacro/xacro.py", line 60, in <module>
    xacro.main()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 672, in main
    doc = parse(f)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/minidom.py", line 1918, in parse
    return expatbuilder.parse(file)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 928, in parse
    result = builder.parseFile(file)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 211, in parseFile
    parser.Parse("", True)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: unclosed token: line 1, column 0
```

I only changed the first lines of the original urdf file that was successfully parsed. I just added this code.

```
<?xml version="1.0">
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro" name="r2d2" >

<xacro:property name="raioRoda" value="0.05"/>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203531/urdf-to-xacro/) by [End-Effector](https://answers.ros.org/users/7606/end-effector/) on ROS Answers with karma: 162 on 2015-02-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems that your xml tag is not closed according to the error. can you try this instead ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
```

can you also make sure that your  tag is closed at the end of the file ?

Hope this helps,

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2015-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your prolog needs to be closed:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2015-02-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1